# not working jquery in a ajax loaded part

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i loaded some pages ajax with [Ajaxtabs](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/) and i used in pages jquery & owl carousel but after load parts ,jquery doesn't work and givenot [owl](http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) classes and styles to divs.

my home page:

```
<div class="tabsbar">
  <ul id="countrytabs" class="tabsheader container">
  <li><a href="#" rel="#default" class="selected">first tab no ajax</a></li>
  <li><a href="one.php" rel="countrycontainer">test tab ajax</a></li>
  <li><a href="two.php" rel="countrycontainer">test tab ajax</a></li>
  <li><a href="three.php" rel="countrycontainer">test tab ajax</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="countrydivcontainer" class="tabsbody">
<p>first tab content that no ajax</p>
</div>
```

one.php & two.php & three.php are my wordpress custom pages link

in one.php :

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPage1 */ ?>
<div class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'print', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
                <div class="product item">

                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                        <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="287px" height="227px" />'; ?>

                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                        <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>

                    </a>

                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

                </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.products').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2,
        },
        768:{
            items:4,
        },
        992:{
            items:6,
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

as you see i saved 10 woocommerce post in a page and i want load it as ajax, the html codes loaded good but the jquery doesnot work on this ajax loaded parts.

another Weird problem when i place the carousel in first tab in #countrydivcontainer that is not ajax for first view in browser work correctly but when i switched between tabs and load another parts and come back to first tab, this also not working.

Comment: Try to change to jQuery UI tabs and use the load event to setup your carousel !

Answer (score 0):

Check you are calling latest jQuery

```
check also that you have added wp_head(); in header.php and wp_fooer(); in footer.php
```

Comment: i just gave that because you may forget that.. nothing else

Comment: i called jquery and i have Other slider & carousel &... and them work good